# What is the best scenario to upload various file where each file is more then 100 MB?

Tags: php, file-upload, uploading, multifile-uploader

i'm uploading these files in apache, using php. is there any best way to make uploading faster ?

Comment: Do you have to upload them through HTTP? and Are your users going to upload files at the same time?

Comment: yes, the use can upload them via http, but also from any other protocol. it's not restricted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading via HTTP isn't the fastest. For such big file cosider using FTP protocol.

Comment: Wrong: FTP is not faster. There are some protocols which have integrated comrpession (e.g. scp). FTP is no faster than HTTP, indeed HTTP can use compression in both directions therefore can be faster than FTP. But still not recommended for transferring large files

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you enable gzip on the server too http://www.mydigitallife.info/2010/04/17/how-to-enable-gzip-compress-on-php-websites/

Comment: That refers to compression in the server responses.

Comment: I guess you're right, you'll just want to enable mod_gzip or mod_deflate.